# How to Convert this to a ternary operator

Tags: php, if-statement, ternary-operator

I want to convert this code to a ternary operator:

```
if (isset($a)) {
    $arr[$k] += $c;
}
else {
    $arr[$k] = $c;
}
```

I can do it if it were a single operator, but, operators are different in `if` and `else`.

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible conversion algorithm with your case (like school algebra)

1. Direct conversion.

   `isset($a) ? ($arr[$k] += $c) : ($arr[$k] = $c);`
2. Explode +=

   `isset($a) ? ($arr[$k] = $arr[$k] + $c) : ($arr[$k] = $c);`
3. Move assignment to the left

   `$arr[$k] = isset($a) ? ($arr[$k] + $c) : ($c);`
4. Move $c

   `$arr[$k] = (isset($a) ? $arr[$k] : 0) + $c;`

And variant without ternary(as bonus).

```
$arr[$k] = $c + isset($a) * $arr[$k];
```

Comment: I think it's bad form to use ternary operators for flow control (i.e. which statement to execute); better style to limit them to where you use them to select one or other value and using it as a return value. Where flow control is desired the if(){} is more readable. But this is a matter of style and readability.

Answer (score 4):

Isn't it just:

```
$arr[$k] = isset(a$) ? ($arr[$k]+$c) : $c
```

or equivalently:

```
$arr[$k] = $c + (isset($a) ? $arr[$k] : 0)
```

Comment: nvm, for some reason, i thought he was handling strings.